# How to make woocommerce shop page with a custom post type +and a checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am sharing 3 screens step by step will be through woocommerce.
I have a shop page. On selecting a product,  I will go to a front end form for creating a post. After creating a post I will go to checkout page.

My question is that, can I get the middle one (front end form for creating a post) in woocommerce platform ?

Please look my shared screen for understanding it better.

Thank you

First Screen

[image: first screen]

Second Screen
[image: second screen]

Third Screen
[image: third screen]

Comment: *It will be 3 screen

Comment: Great, Developer of this project need a help for the first time that too when almost everything in the project is completed..... Is this your second or more account??? Also you haven't describe your doubt very well so that we can understand the problem and try to get the solution.... Voting for closing it.....

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that, can I get the middle one (front end form for
>   creating a post) in woocommerce platform ?

Sure, but you have to save the data from step 2 in the current session (cart).
Only when an order is created, collect the session data and create the (custom_post_type) job post. You don't want to create the job post before the order is completed / paid for.

Your question is very general, so you can expect a similar answer. We do not build complete plugins here. You will need to use multiple hooks to complete this.

**EDIT: some more info**

@ step 2, collect, sanitize and validate the form values.
I would save this data in the cart session. something like this:

```
// I don't know how and where you collect the step 2 data,
// so i can't provide a hook for this function.

function step_2_data_to_session() {
  global $woocommerce;
  $step_two_data = array();

  // validate and sanitize data first

  // save data to woocommerce session
  $woocommerce->session->set('step_two_data', $step_two_data );
}
```

Then when the user pays and creates an order, use a hook to collect the session data and save it to your costom post type.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'new_order', 10, 2)
function new_order($order_id,  $data) {
  global $woocommerce;

  // At this point the order is created and the session data is still alive.

  if(! is_admin() ) {
    $step_two_data = $woocommerce->session->get('step_two_data');
    if($step_two_data) {
      $args = array(
        'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_title' => 'The Job title here',
        'post_type' => 'job',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
      );
      $new_job_post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
      if($new_job_post_id) {
        // Job post is saved now..
        // Now you'll probably want to add step_two_data as meta data to the post.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** I haven't tested this code, error handling is not included, etc. This is just a pointer how to save the session data when the order is created.

You'll have to do much more, for example, i see that the job listing has a set expiration date. I would use a cron-job to daily check which jobs have to be removed, with the same cron i would also inform customers their job post '*will be removed in 2 days*' etc etc ;-)

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Hello Bjorn,
can you clear little bit more for this process. I created a custom post type for (job post) and also created shop page. but I need idea how to merge this 2 functionality. please clear the hooks.

Thanks, Sah Alam

Comment: I've added some more info to my answer. I can't do anything more, sorry. To succesfully complete this project i recommend you contact someone with enough WP and WOO knowledge.